# MySQL Trigger INSERT copy's rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create a trigger (this is my first trigger, and question, so be gentle) that will insert new rows into two different tables.

*** Edit ***

Adding this in as I forgot to mention it until [ypercube](https://stackoverflow.com/users/344949/ypercube) answered.
I am trying to avoid listing all of the column names, as in the real world usage the table this will be used on has a very large number of columns (not my design, too late to refactor).

*** End Edit ***

Here's what I have so far.

```
CREATE TABLE test_table (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    message VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE test_table_copy LIKE test_table;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER copy_test_table_data AFTER INSERT ON test_table
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO test_table_copy SELECT * FROM NEW;
END;$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Unfortunately this results in an error.

```
mysql> INSERT INTO test_table VALUES (1, 'This is a message');
ERROR 1146 (4502): Table 'test_db.NEW' doesn't exist
```

I am not quite sure what the problem is, I thought NEW referred the table data was being inserted into?

Comment: `NEW` is not a table and cannot be used in the `FROM` clause like this. Try `INSERT INTO test_table_copy SELECT NEW.id, NEW.message;`

Comment: Or: `INSERT INTO test_table_copy VALUES(NEW.id, NEW.message);`

Comment: I was trying to keep from having to list each of the column names as in the real world example this will be used in, there are a crap load of columns (not my design, too late to refactor). Is there a way to do that?

Comment: What's wrong with copy-pasting a few column names (and attaching `NEW.`)? You are only going to write the trigger once. You could use this: `INSERT INTO test_table_copy SELECT t.* FROM test_table AS t WHERE t.id = NEW.id ;` as the `id` id the primary key.

Comment: One of the tables is 93 columns, I don't see the structure changing anytime soon, but if it does, I would have to change both tables, which isn't a problem, but also drop the trigger and recreate it. If I am not the developer on this later down the road, it's going to throw the new one for a loop until he figures it out.<br/>  
      
    Don't think I am trying to discount your suggestion, I just want to be sure that this is the only option first ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could possibly get a list of column names in that table from `information_schema` views, then use them to create a prepared statement (using cursor to iterate column names) and `CONCAT()` function to glue together the query string. Then execute the prepared statement.
Seems very contrived even to me, and I'm not sure it would work (and if it did, how efficient it would be)

Comment: I am in the processing of testing @ypercube's answer now.  This is a tough one because my predecessor created the relational tables and used 2 columns, both of which are `VARCHAR` data types; as the primary key.  One of these tables is 56.4GB with over 75 million rows. So there is a little bit of overhead by selecting rows.  I was hoping I could just use the data that was already inserted instead, but it doesn't seem like it's going to be too much overhead.